# Regression using plm package and twoways effect, when data has NA

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

So, I'd like to run a regression on a panel data, using two-ways effects, for time and stores. If the panel is perfectly balanced, it works fine, but for some reason, if it's not, the code gets stuck. (see: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-May/239272.html).

My data in particular is not unbalanced in nature, but it has some NAs, so I guess it's becoming unbalanced when the plm function removes rows with NA.
I wrote a sample code to exemplify the data I have.

If I run this:

```
set.seed(123)
library(plm)
number.of.days <- 1100
number.of.stores <- 1000
days <- sort(rep(c(1:number.of.days),number.of.stores))
stores <- rep(c(1:number.of.stores),number.of.days)

data <- cbind.data.frame(stores,days,matrix(rnorm(number.of.days*number.of.stores*7),nrow=number.of.days*number.of.stores,ncol=7))
colnames(data)[3:9] <- c('y',paste0('x',1:6))

data <- plm.data(data,c("stores","days"))  
fit <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, data = data, index=c("stores","days"), effect="twoway", model="within")
```

It works correctly, because the panel is balanced. However, if I create some NA values:

```
data$y[sample(1:number.of.days*number.of.stores,150)] <- NA
data$x1[sample(1:number.of.days*number.of.stores,150)] <- NA
data$x2[sample(1:number.of.days*number.of.stores,150)] <- NA
data$x3[sample(1:number.of.days*number.of.stores,150)] <- NA
data$x4[sample(1:number.of.days*number.of.stores,150)] <- NA
data$x5[sample(1:number.of.days*number.of.stores,150)] <- NA
data$x6[sample(1:number.of.days*number.of.stores,150)] <- NA
```

And try to run the regression again:

```
 fit <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, data = data, index=c("stores","days"), effect="twoway", model="within")
```

It does not work (the code apparently never stops running)

I tried using 'individual' effect for stores and adding a matrix with dummies for time, but since there are 1100 days, it becomes just as slow.

I assume this is not a rare problem. Is there any known solution?

Thank you

Comment: Running your code I got a lack of memory error: `Reached total allocation of 8139Mb: see help(memory.size)`. However, if you reduce your sample size, the error vanishes. Is that the same error you are getting with your real data?

Comment: If I run on Linux server, which is what I usually do, it just never ends. But when I try on local RStudio, yes, this happens. About the size, you are correct, but my real data is just as big

Comment: Please specifiy what you mean by "It does not work". Do you get some kindof error message or what is the behaviour observed that signals "does not work"?

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"? Is the model stopped by an error or the final output is not understandable?

Comment: You can try to set `options("plm.fast" = TRUE)` from plm version 2.4 onwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `felm` function from the [`lfe`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/index.html) package is able to handle this (and efficiently, too).

Running

```
fit2 <- felm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 | stores + days | 0 | stores , data = data)
```

on the data with the `NAs` yields a result.

Note the formula specification in which you specify which factors are to be projected out (i.e. the fixed effects). The last `stores` in the formula specifies the variable for clustering standard errors. For details see the excellent `felm` help file and `lfe` package documentation.